# ArcGIS Pro select-by-location using intersect not working as anticipated

Tags: arcgis-pro

I'm using ArcGIS Pro and I have a polygon layer that needs to be selected if it intersects with another polygon layer in "red", as seen in the picture. However when I use the select-by-location tool and use intersect it selects the entire layer and not just the polygons that intersect.

I've tried using repair geometry, ensured my CRS is matching, and ensured they are not multi-polygons but I haven't figured out what is causing this. Any suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you have multipolygons. Try "multipart to single part" on your first feature class, then run the select by location again.

Comment: Thank you for the comment...It seems restarting ArcGIS pro fixed the problem. Thank you though.