# ArcGIS Pro: Select By Location with option Intersect returns features which are within the selecting feature

Tags: arcgis-pro, select-by-location, intersect

I try to follow the suggestion given in an [equal case](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397233/arcgis-pro-select-by-location-using-intersect-not-working-as-anticipated), however, I do not end up with the desired result. I'd like to select the filled polygons whose boundary crosses the red lined polygon. For this, I apply `Select By Location` with the option `Intersect` for the filled polygons with the red lined polygon as `Selecting Feature`. However, this process also selects features which are (completely) within the `Selecting Feature` (left image). It is verified, that the filled polygons are singlepart features: they can get selected individually by manual selection (right image). How should I proceed in order to select polygons only which cross the red lined polygon?

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2 on Windows 11 Pro 22H2.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should use the "Crossed by the outline of" rather than the "intersect" relationship. [Read this](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-location.htm) to get a description of all relationship option.

Note that in some case you cant get the wanted selection in only one operation but you will need to chain several selection by using the "add from current sélection" and/or "remove from current sélection" option, using different relationship...